# Changing Supplied Value to ThemeProvider is not causing components to re-render in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am still new to React but I am facing a strange Problem. Actually I am working on theme translation from right to left for Arabic Language on a existing  project which is also using server side rendering in react. Scenario is, we have our own React Component's Library which we are using in our Main Project. That Component Library has access to "theme" object via ThemeProvider. I have Placed one key named "textDirection" in our theme and now I want my component library to change some css properties dynamically based on that theme.textDirection like, **`textAlign: (theme.textDirection==='rtl'?'left':'right').`**  It works fine for initial Load but when user selects another language form language Dropdown I am dispatching redux store action to modify theme.textDirection but now for client side my library components are not re-rendered.

In the Main Project , client side here I am setting theme provider from redux store.

```
hydrate(
  <ThemeProvider theme={store.getState().config.theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
```

Now even Changing the redux store theme.textDirection, components library gets the same theme object or no re-render happens. 
May Be I am doing something wrong or my approach is not right can anyone please help me in this scenario.

Note: **I want to clear , Main Project is using a React Component Library which has theme obejct via ThemeProvider. Now I want to change Components Library CSS when user in Main Project selects a new language from Language Dropdown.**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are actually changing the theme. From your perspective it could looks like you are changing it but from `ThemeProvider` it can looks differently. It probably compare the theme and if there is no change, then it will not re-render. Because the theme is object it will be compared by reference... If you do not have immutable structure, then you will have same reference even if the object has different props..

Try this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{ ...store.getState().config.theme }}>
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

This will make the theme to be new object every time - note this should be OK as long as you have your `ThemeProvider` at top level, otherwise it can cause performance issues...